# Alter default form mark-up in CakePHP?

Tags: php, html, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Is it possible to change the form mark-up generated by CakePHP when creating forms using the `Form` helper?

I really don't want to go through all of my view files and manually specify mark-up for the `before`, `after` and `between` parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$this->Form->create('Model', array('inputDefaults' => array('before' => ...)'))` The inputDefaults option takes any of the presentational arguments that input() does, and are applied to every call of input()

Another way would be to extend the Form helper and make it output your defaults. Up to you!

Comment: So where would I place this code? And am I right in thinking that passing `Model` as the first parameter will affect every model, given they all extend `AppModel` which in turn extends `Model` (I think)?

Comment: That is on each view where you create a form. If you do not wish to do it for each view, the best thing is to create another helper extending the FormHelper, override the create() function to have the inputDefaults already preset.